# What is the maximum storage capacity of a plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist, storage

My application uses a `plist` as data storage, and I would like to know, what is the **maximum storage capacity** of a plist file in iOS?

Comment: I imagine the same as your free hard disk space

Answer (score 6):

A `plist` **can be of arbitrary length**.

Apple, however, only recommend `plists` having a maximum size of [a couple hundred KB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/propertylists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html):

> "For situations where you need to store small amounts of persistent
>   data—say less than a few hundred kilobytes—property lists offer a
>   uniform and convenient means of organizing, storing, and accessing the
>   data."

For data which is more memory intensive, they recommend the following:

> "In some situations, the property-list architecture may prove
>   insufficient. If you need a way to store large, complex graphs of
>   objects, objects not supported by the property-list architecture, or
>   objects whose mutability settings must be retained, use [archiving](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-BAJDBJAI)."

Comment: Hi, I just want to know whether a plist can hold 100 dictionaries which has only text.

Comment: @Bing It should be no problem at all. My Guess.

Answer (score 1):

plist is a file format. It is only constrained by the maximum file size. The way it's read and written poses another constraint: the memory available to hold serialized objects.