# Size limit that an iOS app can dynamically expand to?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing an iOS app, where in a certain scenario, the app will download number of images from our server and store image data into a file and have the reference in a plist file and placed in documents directory. I would like to know what is the limit of the app can expand the size when its running on iOS device? I am asking this because, my app may download 100 images from server and store their image data into a file file, that will expand the app size more dynamically.

Please advise.

Comment: You will store the actual image data into a `.plist` file?

Comment: Yes, I'll store the actual image data into plist file. Is there any other option I can store the downloaded image data within the app?

Comment: Do you understand the implications of doing that?  You seem concerned about file sizes and yet choose one of the least efficient storage mechanisms.

Comment: Could you suggest the efficient storage mechanisms please? When I asked for the suggestion in another query, i got suggested to store in documents directory.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383725/what-is-the-maximum-storage-capacity-of-a-plist) I think you should save  filePath instead image data in plist file

Comment: @Stella How does storing within the `Documents` folder equate to using `.plist` files?  Simply store the file data in a file and hold references to those files within a `.plist` file, if you have to.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same way. I am storing image data into Documents dir in a file, and having the reference path link in plist file. That's correct. Is there any maximum expandable limit to store image in documents directory? Could you advise please?

Answer (score 2):

The only limit is the amount of free space on the device, there is no other limit. But Apple might reject your app if you are storing lots of data you can re-download in the documents directory. The rules state that data the app can re-download must not be stored in places where it is backed up to iCloud. That would mean you have to store it in the Library/Caches folder or set the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey resource value.

If you store data in the caches directory you must be prepared to download it again at any time since the system might decide to clear that folder at any time if it's low on disk space.

If you follow these simple rules you can store as much data as you want to. But here is another issue: I wouldn't recommend storing large amounts of binary data as a property list file. A better approach would be to store each image in its own file. If you store them all in a single property list file you have to load them all at once which requires a lot of memory and takes more time.

Comment: ok thanks.I read about 4 GM app limit. Can't be expanded, Is that right?

Comment: That is the limit for the size of the app as distributed at the App Store.

Comment: ok thank you. Is there any sample to achieve this, "A better approach would be to store each image in its own file." ?